# What is the best way to deploy to a standalone Weblogic Server ADF Secure Application with maven

Tags: java, maven, weblogic, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I'am looking since some days ago to the right way to deploy my ADF Secure Web project with maven to Weblogic server(WLS)

My problem is this file `jazn-data.xml` which contains informations about users/groups(roles)/grants. During the deploy process to WLS the jazn-data.xml muss be merged into `system-jazn-data.xml`. The system-jazn-data.xml is used by WLS to know about the securities settings of an application.

I add this to my weblogic-application.xml which is supposed to merge jazn-data.xml into system-jazn-data.xml but nothing

```
<listener-class>oracle.adf.share.weblogic.listeners.ADFApplicationStateListener</listener-class>
```

Does somebody already do this with success? Thanks for all informations

Answer (score 1):

Which version are you using, because if you are using 12c it should [come out of the box with JDeveloper!](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm)

Or else try to use [OEPE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-11118-521475.html)(Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse) as it packages the application without OJDeploy, you can use that and create your Maven script to take the generated war file and resume from there.

Comment: I'AM USING 12C. But my problem is not Jdeveloper problem. But maven and deployment descriptor

Comment: Sorry for being late, I'm just trying to do that myself and everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

@Festus sorry for being late, you can download the project from [here](http://www.amr-gawish.com/MavenWithSecurity.zip), I created one role and have one page in this simple application, I packaged the application using mvn package and installed it in weblogic using Weblogic Console.

One problem I had is my Model connection, I remove the database connection from connections.xml and pointed the model to a weblogic datasource and the application installed successfully.

Comment: I just try your application but unfortunatly doesn't help me at all. The problem is that the jazn file must me pack to the war file and during the deployment process should be merge to system-jazn-data.xml on the WLS

Comment: I can't see this scenario in a real life application, this can be helpful for testing and development, but when it comes to real life applications, all users and enterprise roles should be already defined in system-jazn-data and you only have to define your application roles!
Saying that you may consider using WLST command line to do the merging before deploying so that you don't worry about it!

Comment: You can also check the note in this article: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/core.1111/e10043/addlsecfea.htm#CFHGBDEG

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that i'am using SQL Authenticator(user/password/roles come from Database) and i don't have the right to start a WLST script on the foreign server.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try doing what's in this picture before deploying to maven, also remove users and groups!

This window can be accessed from Application properties

[image: disable weblogic-config and jazn merging]

Comment: This approch doesn't help so far that i'am deploy from CI(Continuous Integration)

Comment: If you are using CI like hudson you had to have administration privilege to deploy to Weblogic directly, you can use that to execute extra WLST commands for migration of JAZN

Comment: I'am using Jenkins. Do you have a snipet code about how config the WLST Script on a jsf page like welcome.jsf?

Comment: You have to create a python file that you can run on Jenkins server, but again you will need the password for a weblogic administrator!